# Is Lady Gaga right we are fighting COVID-19?

Tags: covid-19, coronavirus

Just a few seconds ago she said that on live streaming global concert to start at 8pm EST April 18, 2020.

I think we are fighting Novel Coronavirus (SARS-COV2) and COVID-19 is something we treat.

Am I wrong?

Comment: The name of the virus is SARS-CoV-2. The name of the disease it causes is COVID-19. So as best I can tell from your anecdotal report, she was correct. This is widely available information you can find with a trivial google search.

Comment: @CareyGregory The disease is visible which the global aid concert was raising money for. It's my assertion we should wage war against the invisible enemy ie the virus. Of course 10% of the virus hosts turn into disease cases and it is important to ventilate them as necessary but the real war (and global fund raising) should be against the virus and not the disease.

Comment: That's fine, but this isn't a platform for opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, "we" are fighting the coronavirus. Or we are fighting the disease caused by coronavirus (COVID-19).

I think it was quite clear what she meant.

We could go into the semantics of whether one can "fight" a non-living thing, but it's probably not a particularly useful debate and is perhaps best left to linguists.

Comment: I think to win the war you have to know the enemy. I view COVID-19 as the victim who we don't need to fight but we need to treat. Sure we need to prevent more COVID-19 victims which is why I think we should focus the fighting on Novel Coronavirus. Still +1 for answering and sharing your thoughts. Thank you.